# How to insert utf-8 title in PHPlot

Tags: php, utf-8

I am trying to set title in PHPlot chart, but in cyrilic characters. For example:

```
$plot = new PHPlot();    
$plot->SetTitle('Наслов');
```

But when I open this in browser then, it shows gibberfish, like this:
[image]

Is possible to set title in unicode in PHPlot?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See section 3.8.5 [at the documentation](http://phplot.sourceforge.net/phplotdocs/conc-text.html).